# C# Posting JSon through System.Net.WebClient causes Unicode translation error

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, unicode

We have a .Net application that posts JSon to a third party web service.  When there are special characters such as a coypyright or trademark in the JSon, we get an exception to the effect of:

Unable to translate bytes [AE] at index xx from specified code page to Unicode.

Example of Json that would return this exception.
{"BrandName":"Proscar®"}

My question is why does this exception only occur when posting from the the application using System.Net.WebClient. When we post this Json through a rest tool such as Fiddler's, it doesn't throw the error.

Comment: Fiddler probably encodes the string to UTF-8

Comment: Thanks. That was it. Changing the default encoding to Utf8 did it.